# Unable to import a private key to Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, private-key, geth-debugging

I downloaded Mist for my computer which runs Ubuntu version 18.04, and tried to import my private key but had these issues:

- When going to FILE > IMPORT ACCOUNTS, the IMPORT ACCOUNTS option is grayed out, and not clickable.
- I then tried going to FILE > BACKUP > ACCOUNTS, I located the "keystore" folder, and placed the UTC JSON file inside, though the mist wallet didn't include the account inside it, even when I reloaded it
- I heard you could use geth to import keys, but I tried typing

  ```
  geth
  ```

  in the terminal to see what happens, and I get

  ```
  geth: command not found
  ```

**QUESTION:** Why can't I import keys to the mist wallet? Any information as to what I might be doing wrong or what other options I can try out would be very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Mist version will install you the geth, if not you have to install it manually. You can follow [this doc](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installing-Geth) to do it